# Adding JVM system properties to running JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

I have a running Java program which I would like to control at the command line by changing a custom system property which I'm listening for changes to inside the application, thereby not requiring a restart of the application for the changes to take affect.

I understand that it's possible to change some of the default JVM properties using jinfo but it doesn't seem to work for custom properties which I set at compile time using the -D flag.

For example, if I start a JAR using the following command line arguments:

```
java -Dfoo=1 -jar my_jar.jar
```

attempting to call the following fails:

```
jinfo -flag foo=2 'pid'
```

Is there something I'm missing or is this simply not possible?

Comment: Its very much possible. What properties are you trying to change? Paste your code.

Comment: They're custom properties I'm setting when compiling/running the JAR, what they are is irrelevant since they're simply keys and values. My question is simply whether or not they can be changed without restarting the application.

Comment: basically not but you can retrieve them in your app from somewhere. in big applications a common practice is to keep the properties on separate service.
it may be helpful https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config

Comment: System properties are generally cached so if you did change them the code using that value would need to poll the value again.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. This utility is unsupported and might not be available in future releases of the JDK. [Official Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jinfo.html)
> 2. Not all of the available parameters can be changed. [Reference](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-change-jvm-arguments-at-runtime-to-avoid-application-restart-816682109.html)

IMO, Recommended way is to have some event-listener or service call to change the flags of running application.
I had used some system properties using jinfo so not sure if custom flags can be changed during jar execution. Try some custom boolean flag using command `jinfo -flag +<customBooleanFlag> <PID>` to check if its working.